# Xpath - how to get text from li class that is not within a tags

Tags: xpath

```
<ul><li>
<a href="/example" class="my class">A name of something</a>
by <a href="/url-example">Hello World</a> (1975)
</li></ul>
```

How do I get the text at the end of the tag here which is "(1975)"?
Also is it possible to have xpath remove the brackets as well?

```
/ul/li
/ul/li/a
/ul/li/a[2]
```

I have tried these so far but still cannot isolate the "(1975)". Any help greatfully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath expression to get the last text node from `<li>` element :

```
/ul/li/text()[last()]
```

**UPDATE :**

You can use `substring-after` and `substring-before` to extract text after `(` and before `)` :

```
substring-before(substring-after(/ul/li/text()[last()], "("), ")")
```